# Convert large Excel Sheet to Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have an excel sheet that contains almost 67,000 rows , and i tried to convert as mysql using `excel_reader`. But its not supporting large number of items. Please help to solve this issue.

Comment: export the excel sheet to CSV and import it with mysqlimport

Answer (score 1):

Try also [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com). You can import large data from Excel with this library. It includes a library as COM component, that can be used from PHP. COM objects are a little slower, but you can obtain a reasonable importing time.
Use this link as starting point:
https://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/import-excel-to-mysql.html

Answer (score 1):

A viable option (But certainly not the easiest) would be to construct a script using php  -- Note this would be the loop itself; you would need your db connection etc etc.

```
<?php
$file = fopen("import.csv","r");
while(! feof($file))
{
 //MYSQL insert Statement here
}
fclose($file);
?>
```

That would create an array for every line then you can use the array positions in your insert statement which will be repeated roughly 67,000 times Wouldnt take excessively long but may be a better approach than using say phpmyadmin if it is timing out on you etc etc.